# Flash/Session messages in cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp-2.0

How to show flash messages in a page without losing POST request? What I am trying to say is show some error flash messages and prevent from loading the page so that I can also prevent losing entered data?

Currently I am doing this in my controller:

```
$this->Flash->error('All fields are required');
$this->redirect($this->referer());
```

And what happen is the flash message will be shown but my data is now gone.

Comment: Redirecting is what causes the data to be lost. Just remove that line.

Comment: You should show your html code otherwise it's gonna be hard to guess what's going on with theses 2 lines of code..